# Why does my 14G USB Not allow a 6.5GB file to be copied over?

Tags: windows, usb

My 14G USB is clear of any other data. I have also reformated it with a FAT drive. 
when I attempt to copy my 6.5 GB file over I get a message saying that my 6.5GB file is too big for the drive.

What is going on, and how to I get the USB to accept it ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file size limit for FAT is 4 GB.

Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table)

> Max. file size    4,294,967,295 bytes (4 GB - 1) with FAT16B and FAT32

Comment: So ... I guess I should reformat to NTFS ?

Comment: @Vince if you are on Windows, yes.